# Automatic editing of pushed documents

Tags: git

I'd like to know if there is way to automatically edit documents pushed to the git server.

Scenario:

1) I locally edit a document. I make some commits. After I'm finished, I push changes to the remote server.

2) Server receives changes and edits a document and it fills inside information about who made last edit and date&time.

I found hooks, which would be perfect, but I see a problem. If I make a commit localy, the SHA code is calculated from files. If server changes it after the push, it becomes inconsistant because the SHA would be different.

The thing is, I need to make those changes on the server, it's the only way to enforce this politic.

Comment: All information on who edited it last etc can already be found in the commit object. Why would you want to save this information redundantly?

Comment: I set up git server in our company. We write our manuals in markdown, and we manage versions in git. On a single manual can cooparate more than 1 person. Every night we want our manuals to be automaticaly updated (generated with pandoc into HTML manual). Now I see that it would be batter to make script, which insert informations we need before it is passed to pandoc.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct git" answer here is "don't do it". As you noted, the server cannot make that change unless you want to generate an auto-commit with the information for every accepted commit.

A way to do most of what you're asking would be to set up [pre-commit hooks](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample) locally to add the information (date and username) before the commit, and thus its SHA hash, is finalized. The downside is that, as far as I know, each locally cloned repository must have this hook set up separately.

You could then set up a [pre-receive hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L210) on the server to make sure that only commits that include this required information can be pushed up.

Perhaps other ways to achieve the goal would be less cumbersome? As @Zeeker noted, the information is already in the commit object and thus in the repo history log - perhaps just educating repo users on how to find this data would suffice? (And this would be a good opportunity to introduce stuff like [git blame](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) too!) Or, you could have a script that collects all the commit authors/dates and enters them into the files and makes a commit, and you'd run it weekly/monthly/before a release.